# Display arrows when hover in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a datepicker like this:

[image]

And when I do hover, appeared the three arrows to change days or to show calendar.

And I would like to remove this arrows.

This is the code:

```
link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      if (attr.type !== 'date') return;
          var calendarioIco=angular.element('<div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>');
          calendarioIco.on('click',function(){
              element.datepicker('show');
          })
          element.before(calendarioIco);
            jQuery(element).datepicker({
                autoclose:true,
                language:'es',
                weekStart:1,
                format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
            }).on('changeDate', function(dateText, inst){
                    jQuery(jQuery(element).data('greater')).datepicker("setStartDate",
                    jQuery(element).datepicker("getDate"));
                 }).on('mouseenter', function (){
                            $(this).removeClass("hover");

                 });
    }
```

Thanks you and sorry about my english,

Comment: This question is unanswerable without more details about how your picker is implemented. Can you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Done @nloewen .

Comment: Can you post css for `.input-group-addon`

Comment: I havent got css for input-group-addon , only of bootstrap @ovokuro

Comment: I think becouse the input have a type="date", change it to type="input"

Comment: If I change to "input", datepicker not works :( @Roy

Comment: Couse  if (attr.type !== 'date') return;...

Comment: also, it would be good to know which html is being rendered by jquery.datepicker. Is it an input="date" or and input="number"?

Comment: input="date" @gabrielperales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to remove them with this snippet:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  display: none;
}
```

You can see an example under this lines

```js
$('#withoutArrows').datepicker({});
$('#withArrows').datepicker({});
```

```css
input[type="date"].clear-style::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="date"].clear-style::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator,
input[type="date"].clear-style::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>



<div class="col-md-4"><input id="withoutArrows" type="date" class="form-control clear-style"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input id="withArrows" type="date" class="form-control"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) @gabrielperales